# xExchange API: the price of a LP token is 0

Tags: graphql, multiversx

I'm querying the xExchange's GraphQL API, but when I'm requesting the price of an LP token the field `price` is 0 (but it shouldn't). Does anyone know how to fetch the price of an LP token through this API?

Here is the query I'm doing:

```
query {
  pairs(firstTokenID: "BUSD-40b57e") {
    liquidityPoolToken {
      identifier,
      price
    }
  }
}
```

The response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pairs": [
      {
        "liquidityPoolToken": {
          "identifier": "BUSDWEGLD-c3b2f6",
          "price": "0"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I got the solution from a member of the xExchange's team.

For LP tokens, the field `price` is not used. Instead, we should use the `liquidityPoolTokenPriceUSD` field available under the `pair` query, like this:

```
query {
  pairs(firstTokenID: "BUSD-40b57e") {
    liquidityPoolTokenPriceUSD
  }
}
```

And the response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pairs": [
      {
        "liquidityPoolTokenPriceUSD": "77.1959373311156606038999772721289720677588609448209439346070102479305240341465078296"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```